# Cron fails when calling hook_node_view

Tags: 7, cron

When running cron manually via GUI the cron starts to run but I have traced down the failure to hook_node_view in one of my modules.

The code is:

```
if ($node->nid == 47)
{
     //THIS CODE IS HAPPENING, but HOW in hook_node_view when running cron?
     drupal_goto('node/48'); 
}
```

Comment: what's in node/47 ?

Comment: It is a database content type node. There are no other hook crons anywhere.

Comment: well cron calls search to index your site, and that would open each node to check for what's inside...

Comment: Is the drupal_goto inside a custom module? If not in what contrib/core module it is (file and line No. please)? If it is in a custom module, like @tostinni said, you should check for the `$view_mode == 'full'` argument, if not it that drupal_goto will never let your cron finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you implement [`hook_node_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7), don't forget to check if you're really displaying the node using this code:

```
function MYMODULE_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
  if ($view_mode == 'full' && node_is_page($node)) {
    //Do something...
  }
}
```

This should correct your errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive about Drupal 7, but I think I had a similar problem with Drupal 6.

My recollection is that the node is "viewed" when it is being indexed by the search module.

You can try disabling the search module, and then run cron.